# fill array of pointers to integer

Tags: c

I wrote a simple code to create an array of pointers to integer and then fill it with scanf while I was using k&R book to do such things this time I tried to use malloc function but encountered a weird problem
here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int getArr(int **myArr);
void print(int *myArr, int n);

int main() {
    int *myArr, n;
    n = getArr(&myArr);
    print(myArr, n);
    return 0;
}

int getArr(int **myArr) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    *myArr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", myArr+i); /* here if i put &(*myArr)[i] will work correctly */
    return n;
}

void print(int *myArr, int n) {
    while (n-- != 0) {
        printf("%d\t", *myArr);
        myArr += 1;
    }
    return;
}
```

but what is the difference between this two types of reading input?

Comment: Slow down and add punctuation please.

Comment: `myArr+i` lacks indirection, it's writing on the pointer data.

Comment: Remove the warning pragma, and the compiler will tell what the bug is.

Comment: @dbush Whether OP realizes it or not, they're working in C++. `using namespace std;` wouldn't have compiled otherwise.

Comment: what warning `#pragma warning(disable:4996)` is disabling?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's a MSVC this to disable checks for `strcpy_s` and related.

Comment: so this pragma needs to _stay_!

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expects a `int *`.

The expression `myArr+i` has type `int **` which doesn't match what is expected, while `&(*myArr)[i]` (or alternately `*myArr+i`) has the correct type `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

since you need the value of the pointer to be updated out of the procedure you rightfully did:

```
*myArr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

(except that you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in C)

But after that `*myArr` is the pointer to scan from. `myArr` is a pointer on the pointer. So you need to keep dereferencing `myArr`

```
    scanf("%d", (*myArr)+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `getArr()` function as `myArr` is double pointer & while scanning data you should use `(*myArr) + i)` instead of just `myArr + i`. Also `myArr` is not initialized in `main()` function.

Here is the modified one

```
int getArr(int **myArr) {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                myArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));/*allocate memroy here */
                scanf("%d", (*myArr) + i); 
        }
        return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
int getArr(int **myArr) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    *myArr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", myArr+i); /* here if i put &(*myArr)[i] will work correctly */
    return n;
}
```

Your memory layout looks something like this:

```
myArr  (a pointer who lives on the stack in main() 
|
| (points to)
V
[XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX] (allocated by malloc)
```

The 4 X's together represent an integer, so this is an array of some sequence of them.  When you dereference myArr, you get the pointer to the beginning of the array.  When you index THAT pointer, you get elements in the array.

Your code is not doing that:

```
myArr+i
```

This is treating myArr as a pointer to array, not a pointer to a pointer.  When you provide myArr + i, you're effectively doing this:

```
myArr --------------------> [WRITE HERE]  
|
| 
V
[XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX]
```

(Imagine memory goes left to right, row by row, so that the array is "far" from myArr, and [WRITE HERE] is closer to it.  By adding to the myArr pointer, you're moving into invalid memory areas.  myArr literally holds an address in main (since that's where you originally declared it, and passed its address to this function.)  When you add to it, you are computing an address somewhere in the main stack frame, and scanf treats it as a pointer to an int, and scribbles some bytes somewhere into your stack.

Your alternate syntax is doing something different:

```
&(*myArr)[i]
```

This dereferences myArr, fetching the beginning of your malloc'd array, then indexes into the array for the i'th offset int, then takes the address of that int and passes it to scanf.

The reason this works this way is that [] has higher precedence than &, and so it's equivalent to this:

```
&((*myArr)[i])
```

This is the correct way to access your memory given this scheme.

It is good to learn this, but the days of K&R C-style coding are fading, especially in c++ code bases, as the danger and error-prone nature of working with raw pointers like this (as you've discovered) have fortunately been superseded by c++ idioms to help encapsulate memory access and reduce hard to comprehend bugs.

Comment: right, I found what was the problem from the first comment but still wasn't sure where myArr+i pointing, thanks to your answer now know that too.